# How to parse json and show data in a dropdown button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON structure which looks like this

```
[
   {
      "term_id":"28",
      "name":"Audi",
      "slug":"audi",
      "term_group":"0"
   }
]
```

In my HTML page, I have a dropdown button where I want to show the name after the click. To do this I have some Javascript code which looks like this:

```
var serviceURL = "http://www.dohamark.com/samudra/";

var make;

$('#make1').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getEmployeeList();
});

function getEmployeeList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + '1st.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, employee) {
            $('#make1').append('<option>' + employee.name + '</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

However, this script shows nothing in the dropdown button click but a blank place. I am very new in JavaScript and don't know much about JSON parsing. Could somebody help identify my mistake?

Comment: Is the AJAX request actually successful.  I ask because I wonder if the request is being made to a different domain than the one the webpage is running on.

Comment: As @MikeBrant mentioned. Check your console for errors. Copy-pasting the JSON content as string is working. Here is the [fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DJwv9/](http://jsfiddle.net/DJwv9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function (index, employee) {
    $('#make1').append('<option>' + employee.name + '</option>');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KYtph/2/

Your code is fine. Make sure it's not cross domain as other have suggested and that it's parsed correctly as json.

Comment: Ok I will let you know after a try

Comment: @iGanja Employee is defined as a return variable in the `each` callback. You can use `value` as the jquery docs do or whatever you want.

Comment: now that you have edited it, it makes sense. however, I never pass it to the controlling function, unless I need the index. which in this case, you don't.

Comment: @iGanja Not everybody grasps the concept of `this` and you're defining something that's already available in the callback. Not really hurting anything and it helps with clarification. Personal choice and not much of a performance hit.

Comment: I don't make assumptions about the level of understanding of basic programming constructs. my bad.

Comment: @iGanja, the parameters are always sent to the callback function; even if you don't specify them as function arguments; `$.each(['a','b','c'], function(){ console.log(arguments) })` will print: `[0, "a"]`, `[1, "b"]` and `[2, "c"]`

Comment: let me remove my previous comment, since the answer has been edited, and no longer applies.

Comment: Your Answer (jsfiddle example) works fine but the exact same code doesnt run in my server, is that an issue of JQUERY and JAVASCRIPT?

Comment: @Reyjohn perhaps you could post what domain your app is on versus the serviceURL? As others have clearly stated, this could easily be a cross domain restriction, and nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
for (var index in employee) {
    $('#make1').append($('<option>').text(employee[index].name));
});
```

If I am reading your question correctly, I think that should do it.

**EDIT** - Just to make sure that it's clear to the OP, when I am use the variable `employee` in the `for in` loop, that should reference the JSON that was returned.

Comment: Check this link http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.forinloop about `for ... in` loop; Also, you're doing the same thing that he did, but with more code :S

Comment: I've been using this same approach on a current project to do exactly what he is trying to do and from JSON feed to a new option.  It works correctly across all browsers.  I can see the point about the Prototype issue in the link, but if he is sure that his data is not going to fall into that situation, I'm not sure why it would be a problem.

Comment: I'm also not sure how it is more code, I simplified the iteration by removing the entire function declaration . . .

Comment: In fact, the undesired behavior of `for in` loop happens when a map (an Object) is used as the element to be iterable. When an array is used, the variable `x` in `for x in array` works as the array index; so your code works without the hasOwnProperty, sorry about this.
Just to be more semantic, I would edit your code to rename `data` as `employees` and `employee` as `index`, also caching the `$("#make1")` would be better for performace;

Comment: Good point, that would better match the original code.  And yeah, I was confused how an index (effectively) was going to cause a problem there.   LOL  Updating.

Comment: I read the question thusly: data is an array of objects of type employee. if you are iterating through those objects using a for...in loop, then your iterator is the object itself and there is no reason to use an indices. it is simply object.property

Comment: @iGanja - From my experience with this, the `for in` loop will assign string indexes as the "keys" to each object in a structure like this one, since there is no actual key assigned to the sub-data.  If the structure were set up as `["employee": {"term_id":"28", "name":"Audi", . . .` it would be a different situation.  Without that, though, the first object gets the key of `"0"`, the second gets `"1"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like so:

```
$.each(data, function () {
    $('#make1').append('<option>' + this.name + '</option>');
});
```

Also, @Mike Bryant makes a good point; if you are going cross domain, this will never work without something like JSON-P.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code :

```
    var dd = $("#make1");

    $(dd).empty();
    $(dd).append($('<option />').attr('value', '-1').text('-----Select----'));
     $.each(data, function(index, employee) {
        dd.append($('<option />').attr('Value',employee.ID).text(employee.Name));
    });
```